# How to edit detail issue page in Jira

Tags: jira

i want to know, how to edit the detail issue page in Jira 7. We don't need information like "Organisation" or "Components". I'm not able to find a mask in which i can edit the shown field and delete the not needed ones.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `Project settings -> Screens` of your project, if you have the correct permission, you can edit the fields to show.

Be careful of what you hide/show because usually the screens are shared between projects.